# Angular with Flex-Layout

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-flex-layout

I wanted to start working with Angular and Flex-Layout framework. I installed flex-layout via npm and imported it in app.module.ts like this:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

imports: [
FlexLayoutModule
],
```

IntelliJ says always: "Class FlexLayoutModule is not an Angular module"

Is this a known issue? How to work with this framework?

Comment: Are you getting any error with `ng build` or 'ng serve`?

Comment: Maybe you could try to remove your node_modules and package-lock.json and then npm install again

Comment: @KathakDabhi If I do ngServe I get many errors This is one of them:

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/base/base2.d.ts:24:19 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

24     protected get parentElement(): HTMLElement | null;

Comment: removing Node_modules worked for me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment von Max K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390067/angular-with-flex-layout/60391316#comment106829895_60390067) solved the problem.

> Maybe you could try to remove your node_modules and package-lock.json and then npm install again